# sql select string between two strings in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, search, opencart

I have a table for example - TABLE. In the table is column name - CUSTOME_FIELDS. in this column I have data like this:

```
{"6":"Name of company","1":"11111111","2":"564974195","4":"","5":"","3":""}
```

I need to take - Name of the company - and give it to new column - NEW_COLUMN.

How can I do that? I tried something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CUSTOME_FIELDS, CHARINDEX('"6":"', CUSTOME_FIELDS), CHARINDEX('","1"',CUSTOME_FIELDS)) FROM TABLE
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please refrain from urgent begging when posting questions, thanks. It is not urgent for anyone but you.

Comment: This is JSON data. You really, **really** want to use a JSON parser on it.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case your MySQL version is 5.7 or higher, and because the data appears to be in `JSON` format, you could try your luck with `json_extract`:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM json_extract(CUSTOME_FIELDS, '$."6"')) AS name FROM your_table;
```

[Demo link](http://rextester.com/URP99685)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have MySQL 5.5.53. Do you have other suggestion which will work on it?

Comment: To keep the things simple, you could either (1) Upgrade MySQL to 5.7 or higher, (2) Fetch the entire column in a PHP variable and use `json_decode()`. If neither of them sound feasible, then you'll be left with the only option to write a query as described in one of the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're storing JSON data in your database, use MySQL 5.7 or better and use a [`JSON` column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). This means you can easily extract data:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$."6"') FROM mytable;
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know about json support in MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your actual data ALL look like:

If your data all look like above example, then you can cut string from **{"6":"** and next **","** :

```
SELECT substring_index(
    substring_index(CUSTOME_FIELD, '{"6":"', -1),
    '","',
    1
)
```

Comment: It gives me an error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'CUSTOME_FIELD' in '%s' field list
but the column is overthere. The data should take between:
start - '"6":"'
end - '","1"'

Any suggestion?

Comment: @user3709897, you've got to add `FROM your_table` to the given query to avoid `Unknown column` error.